Binding PathIcon Data to Geometry in ResourceDictionary generates runtime error using WinUI-3
I have been getting into WinUI 3, coming from WPF, and started by making a simple user control with an icon and text on it (configured as dependency properties). When I use the control and bind the properties to resources in a resource dictionary, I get the following exception at runtime in App.g.i.cs:

Value does not fall within the expected range.

If I replace the reference to the geometry in the resource dictionary and insert it directly, everything works fine. After spending time experimenting and researching, I've not uncovered why this is the case so I thought I'd reach out here.
I'm confident I'm doing something silly (whether it's an oversight or just a lack of understanding of how things are supposed to work and be setup in WinUI 3). Any help would be much appreciated.
MainWindow.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="Winui3ResourcesTest.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="using:Winui3ResourcesTest"
  mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Winui3ResourcesTest">

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Background="PaleGreen">

    <!-- This works -->
    <!--<local:UserControl1
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Text="{StaticResource Control1Text}"
      Icon="M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z"/>-->

    <!-- This doesn't work -->
    <local:UserControl1
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Text="{StaticResource Control1Text}"
      Icon="{StaticResource Control1Icon}"/>
    
  </StackPanel>

</Window>

MyControl.cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace Winui3ResourcesTest;
public sealed class MyControl : Control
{
  public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Text),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

  public string Text
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
  }

  public static DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Icon),
    typeof(Geometry),
    typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(Geometry)));

  public Geometry Icon
  {
    get => (Geometry)GetValue(IconProperty);
    set => SetValue(IconProperty, value);
  }

  public MyControl()
  {
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
  }
}

Themes\Generic.xaml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="using:Winui3ResourcesTest">

  <Style TargetType="local:MyControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
          <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
              <PathIcon Data="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

ResourceDictionary1.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <x:String x:Key="Control1Text">Hello, World!</x:String>
  <Geometry x:Key="Control1Icon">M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z</Geometry>

</ResourceDictionary>

Project File
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Winui3ResourcesTest</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ResourceDictionary1.xaml" />
    <None Remove="UserControl1.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.6.241114003" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="UserControl1.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="ResourceDictionary1.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Publish Properties -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishReadyToRun Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishReadyToRun Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">True</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">False</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishTrimmed Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">True</PublishTrimmed>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

UPDATE - 12/18/2024
Changing the icon resource from Geometry to String, creating ResourceDictionary contents such as:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <x:String x:Key="Control1Text">Hello, World!</x:String>
  <x:String x:Key="Control1Icon">M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z</x:String>
  <!--<Geometry x:Key="Control1Icon">M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z</Geometry>-->

</ResourceDictionary>

This eliminates the runtime error, but the icon does not render at all. What should be displayed:

What gets displayed instead:


Can you try the following instead of Geometry?
<x:String x:Key="Control1Icon">M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z</x:String>

UPDATE
Since it seems that the string is not converted to Geometry behind the scenes, we need to do that ourselves. In order to do that, we can use the XamlBindingHelper.
For example:
Generic.xaml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <PathIcon x:Name="PathIcon" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

CustomControl1.cs
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathIconDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(PathIconData),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }

    public string PathIconData
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PathIconDataProperty);
        set => SetValue(PathIconDataProperty, value);
    }

    private PathIcon? PathIcon { get; set; }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (GetTemplateChild("PathIcon") is PathIcon pathIcon)
        {
            PathIcon = pathIcon;
            pathIcon.Data = XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Geometry), PathIconData) as Geometry;
        }
    }
}

the use it:
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="TestData">M3,6H21V8H3V6 M3,11H21V13H3V11 M3,16H21V18H3V16Z</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

<local:CustomControl1 PathIconData="{StaticResource TestData}" />


Thanks for the reply, @Andrew! I no longer receive a runtime error, but the icon also isn't rendered at all. I'll up my original post with the results.

I updated my answer. I hope it helps ;)
